# Method Mockito.when().thenReturn() and Mockito.doreturn().when() not returning specified mock value

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mongo

```
    @InjectMocks
    private UserServiceImpl userService;

    @Mock
    private UserRepository  mockUserRepository;



    //private UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;

    @Before
    public void initMocks() throws Exception {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockUserRepository = Mockito.mock(UserRepository.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateUser() {

        User user = createUser();
        Mockito.doReturn(user).when(mockUserRepository).findByEmail(user.getEmail());       

        Mockito.when(mockUserRepository.save(user)).thenReturn(user);
        userService.createUser(user);
    }

private User createUser() {

        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName("Shreya");
        user.setLastName("Mahajan");
        user.setEmail("shreya.mahajan@nitorinfotech.com");
        user.setRole("admin");
        user.setPassword("shreya123");

        return user;

    }
```

This is my actual service method. while testing it gives me null on variables existingUser and response

```
@Override
    public ResponseVO createUser(User user) {
        ResponseVO responseVO = new ResponseVO();
        User existingUser = userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
        if(user.getEmail() != null){
            if(existingUser != null){
                responseVO.setStatusCode("500");
                responseVO.setMessage("user Already Exists");
            }else{              
                User response = userRepository.save(user);
                if(response == null){
                    responseVO.setStatusCode("400");
                    responseVO.setMessage("Failure");                       
                }else{
                    responseVO.setStatusCode("200");
                    responseVO.setMessage("Success");       
                }
            }           
        }
        return responseVO;
    }
```

I am trying to write a test case and mock methods findByEmail() and save() but while mocking i am not receiving the user object in return mentioned in thenreturn() and doreturn().

Can anyone please help.

Comment: Why are you mocking UserRepository twice one using @Mock and then using Mockito.mock in initMocks method?

Comment: Also can you please provide the method under test?

Comment: @ShanuGupta I have just added the actual service method. I am a beginner to this so sorry for some silly mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are somethings you can try:

Please remove `mockUserRepository = Mockito.mock(UserRepository.class);` as its redundant.

Instead of

```
Mockito.doReturn(user).when(mockUserRepository).findByEmail(user.getEmail());
```

do this

```
Mockito.doReturn(user).when(mockUserRepository).findByEmail(Mockito.any());
```

Comment: Great! Keep exploring.